# How to protect email addresses from being read, but make them searchable on the frontend side with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Basically I am trying to figure out a way to get an e-mail address of a user without any authentication on a certain webpage of my app. That said my firebase rules don't allow reading a user's document to avoid leaks, etc.

So in summary: how can I prevent people from reading a user's document but still make them searchable to get some data (i.e an email address)?

Thanks already!

Edit for clearness:

**This is my rules for the user's table:**

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if belongsTo(userId);
    allow create: if belongsTo(userId);
    allow update: if belongsTo(userId);
    allow delete: if false;
}
```

Now, on a certain page on my website, I need to get a certain user's info (which is dynamic): sometimes I would need to get info of **User Bob** and sometimes maybe **User Doe**.

But, my rules right now prevent anyone to get any user's documents information if you are not authenticated and the document doesn't belongs to you.

So what would be the best way to basically bypass this rule `allow read: if belongsTo(userId);` in my code. I was thinking maybe an HTTP request could help me with cloud functions but I'm not sure how to achieve that one.

I hope that makes it more clear. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Could you edit the question show some examples of actual data and queries that you want to allow and reject based on specific criteria?

Comment: @DougStevenson just edited. I hope it's better now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, changing that rule isn't an option since there's sensitive data in those documents that I don't want anyone to be able to get except me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do isn't possible with security rules.  If your rules don't allow read access to a document, then there is no chance of anyone getting data out of it.  It's not possible to write a rule that allows someone to read a document if they simply know some data that's inside it.

You're probably going to have to create an API (using Cloud Functions if you want) that takes the email address as a parameter, performs the query, and sends the whatever result back to the client.

Comment: Would it be possible if I used a callable function in my vuex store like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable? Since this would basically return what I need from the backend it would bypass the rule, I think?

By the way I'm a big fan, your videos helped me a ton in the past!

Comment: Sure, use a callable function if you want.